# Object litterals vs Module pattern

Tags: javascript, class, module

I would like to understand clearly the difference between those two following patterns. In fact, the second one allows to mimic public and private method, but is there any other difference ?

```
var myModule = {

  myProperty: "someValue",
  ...
  myMethod: function () {
    console.log( "Anything" );
  }

};
myModule.myMethod();
```

and this :

```
    var myModule = (function(){
       var myProperty= "someValue";
       ...
       return {
           myMethod: function(){
               console.log('something');
           }
       }

    })();
myModule.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is essentially just like the first, except that it also provides for a closure around the object where "private" variables can be kept.

Specifically, if you set up an example like the second such that it had no local variables and no parameters to the anonymous function, it'd be exactly like not having the anonymous function at all.

Comment: ok so there is no advantage in term of namespacing or anything else ?

Comment: @Newben well one could consider the private closure variables to be an advantage I guess.

Comment: Thinking some module pattern as a Class, it isn't possible to open the class and add some method, right ? (which would be possible with the Object Litterals)

Comment: Sure you can add properties. The anonymous function returns an object, so you're free to add new properties. **However**, you may be thinking about whether those methods can access the "private" variables, and the answer is **no** to that. Only functions created inside that initial anonymous function will be able to "see" the private variables.

Comment: Ok I got it, very interesting